# How is Ruby module inclusion not really 'multiple inheritance' and how does the Ruby style avoid the problems associated with multiple inheritance?

Tags: ruby, multiple-inheritance, mixins

Matz supposedly said "mixins could do almost everything multiple inheritance do, without the associated drawbacks" (Matz words)."

First of all, why is Ruby module inclusion not 'multiple inheritance' ? It seems to me there is very little difference between modules and classes. The fact you cannot instantiate a module is irrelevant when it is used as a superclass.

I also know that successive module inclusion forms a single inheritance chain (not tree) extending upwards from the class. But this, to me, is not sufficient to distinguish it from 'multiple inheritance' as the Python multiple inheritance system also "linearizes" the superclass chain (using the [C3 algorithm](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/)) it's just that Ruby 'linearizing' process is significantly simpler.

So what exactly distinguishes Ruby module mixins from multiple inheritance in say a language like Python? And why don't the arguments behind the Python adoption of the c3 MRO algorithm apply to Ruby? And if they do apply - why did Ruby decide not to adopt this algorithm ?

thanks

Comment: Here is a nice article on that matter, see if it answers your question: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=246488

Comment: @Mladen this is absolutely brilliant....if you add it as a proper answer i'll 'accept' it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this on Mladen's behalf as an actual answer, because I found it very helpful, and I'm guessing answers get indexed better for whatever crazy things SO does with it.

> Here is a nice article on that matter, see if it answers your
>   question: http://artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=246488 – Mladen
>   Jablanović Oct 28 '10 at 18:23

Answer (score 4):

With MI, lots of the issues that arise can be trimmed down to implementation details; you can't just talk about "Multiple inheritance" in general, without talking specifics. So I'll be assuming that you mean "C++ multiple inheritance" when you say "multiple inheritance".

The most common problem with Multiple inheritance is the [Diamond Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem). If several superclasses on the same level define the same method, how do you know which method is invoked on the subclass?

With modules, this problem is easily answered - the last included module always "wins". You can't include several modules "simultaneously", as you can do with classes in C++. So this problem never arises.

> The fact you cannot instantiate a module is irrelevant when it is used as a superclass

I respectfully disagree.

First, modules are never "used as superclasses" in ruby; only superclasses are.

Second, with multiple inheritance, knowing exactly in what order the constructors (& destructors!) are called is [not a trivial matter](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.14). The fact that ruby modules don't allow instantiation suppresses that problem altogether.

Comment: Thanks, however a better comparison would be Python's MI, rather than C++'s. I, respectfully disagree again regarding included modules and 'superclasses' :). An included module operates almost exactly as a 'superclass' does in Ruby - that is the superclass pointer of the class points to the included module (just as it would point to the superclass). Also, the fact that Ruby's modules follow the rule "the last included module always "wins"" could be viewed as simply a linearization algorithm - similar to Pythons's c3 linearization - so i don't see how this in itself differentiates it from MI.

Comment: "almost" is not the same as "exactly". The differences are important. For example, 'super' doesn't work for modules. But in any case I didn't realize this was a Python question. I guess I deserve the -1 :/

Comment: `super` works *in* modules but it doesn't work *for* modules, simply because modules can't be subclassed. A module M can define a method on which `super`, is invoked, but it'll only work if the class on which M is included defines super. Otherwise it'll be undefined.

Comment: if I have two modules (A and B), and B includes A, i then include B into a class C, build an instance and execute a method. If that method is deifned on C, B, A with a 'super' it'll invoke each method and go up the chain. In this example `super` is working in modules fine --- you specificially said 'super doesn twork in modules'. Super works fine in modules. I have no idea what you mean by 'modules cant be subclassed' - in this example B effectively subclasses A, and C subclasses B. And `super` works as you'd expect for subclassing -- it goes up the chain from C to B to A.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the book "Metaprogramming Ruby" from the Pragmatic Press. It contains a very detailed explanation of this, in a manner that is very easy to read and understand. http://pragprog.com/titles/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby

i can't answer mot of your questions because i don't know python. but the basics of why it's not multiple inheritance is that ruby injects the module into the inheritance chain when the module is included or a class is extended by a module.

```
class Foo
  include Bar
end

module Bar
end

foo = Foo.new
```

this produces an inheritance chain where foo is an instance of Foo and Foo inherits from Bar.

it's a bit more tricky than just that, and there are rules for the order in which the inheritance injection occurs. the book i referenced explains it very well.

Comment: Thanks, hehe, but do you think you could summarize in more detail what the book says? Note: I don't need to know the specifics of how the module is injected, more the theory behind why they chose this approach  over the typical multiple inheritance approach and HOW it is different to the normal MI approach. :) Sorry to ask, but I'm not going to buy this book (I already have too many to read hehe).

Comment: I've read "Metaprogramming Ruby", and I don't know the answer to banister's question.

Answer (score 0):

Most important in ruby is you overwrite previous definitions of data/functions with every included module.

So it is bad as every new module should theoretical take care of giving access to previous code which gets overwritten.

So example code to write new module is (logically):

```
old_function = fun
fun = define_new_function
  do_you_staff
  call old_function
```

You do not have to use old function, although in most cases it's useful but sometimes it is easier to rewrite the whole code.

Each included module will build chain of overwritten methods, so there will be no problems with multiple inheritance but order of including modules gets more important.

This method is also called monkey patching - term widely used in Ruby on Rails.